# Load/Parse gltf 3D data from STRING (not from file) with react-three-fiber

Tags: json, string, parsing, gltf, react-three-fiber

Disclaimer:

At first I would like to say I am quite new to web-development - maybe this issue is caused by lacking of elementary knowledge therefore I would be grateful for any helpful advice.

The Issue:

I am trying to load 3D data in gltf format on my web app, however the data is dynamic -> may change while website is used. Since I would like to avoid creating a new file between every change, I would rather upload gltf data from JSON string. This is possible with three library itself:

```
    let loader = new THREE.GLTFLoader();
    loader.parse(JSON.stringify(jsonGltf),'' ,(gltf) => {
        model = gltf.scene;scene.add(model);
    }, true);
```

However I would like to stick with react-three-fiber + drei for its ease of use with React. Unfortunately I cannot find a solution in examples or on someone else's code.

Editable sandbox could be found here:

https://codesandbox.io/s/priceless-knuth-cb1mo?file=/src/App.js

String data are stored in  **const surfGltgData**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is quite simple since GLTFLoader has a parse function. just get your arraybuffer and feed it into the loader. here's an example that still uses suspense so you get some kind of loading screen for long parsing times https://codesandbox.io/s/arraybuffer-dof-1sjyd

Comment: Thank you for explanation and example Mr.Henschel !